# State is being changed, but display not updating

Tags: reactjs

I've seen quite a few posts about this, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

I have a render method that is being mapped to list the different sections stored in a state(this part works as expected):

```
render() {
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Div>
                    <hr />
                    <div>
                        {this.state.sections.map(section => (
                            <div
                                className="mb-3"
                                key={section.section_title}
                            >
                                <h3>{section.section_title}</h3>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
        )
    }
```

However, I have a modal that allows you to create a new section by giving it a name and clicking submit. That does create it and add it to my database table as expected. But, then when I run the method to pull that data down, and change the state to include the new section, it works, and does indeed change the state to include the new section.  But it does not update the display unless I reload the page. Can anyone see why?

```
getProjectSections(projId) {
        fetch(API_URL + `/billingcalculator/sections/distinct/${projId}`)
            .then((res) => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error()
                }
                return res.json()
            })
            .then((result) => {
                let listedSections = [...result];
                this.setState({ sections: listedSections });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

the getProjectSections() runs when you click the submit button a creating a new section which runs this:

```
handleSectionCreateSave() {
        fetch(API_URL + `/billingcalculator/section/create`, {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                projectId: this.props.billProjId,
                sectionTitle: this.state.newSectionTitle
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        })
            .then((res) => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw new Error();
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((data) => console.log(data))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
            .then(this.getProjectSections(this.props.billProjId))
            .then(this.setState({ showSectionModal: false }))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
```

Comment: When does `getProjectSections` run?

Comment: Sorry, I left that out.  I just edited my post to show when it runs.  It's when you click the submit button that creates a new section.  It runs the after the API call that adds new section to the database table.  It does work, and adds the section, and adds to the the state, just doesn't update the display.

Comment: For me, it looks like you should get an error in the console. Do you get any?

Comment: Note that `this.getProjectSections(this.props.billProjId)` is called immediately and the result passed to `.then()`, which is unlikely what you want. `then` takes a function, so give it one, like `.then(() => this.getProjectSections(this.props.billProjId))`. Can't tell if that's the problem here, but it's going to cause problems at some point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling state updates before request happens:

```
handleSectionCreateSave() {
    fetch(API_URL + `/billingcalculator/section/create`, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            projectId: this.props.billProjId,
            sectionTitle: this.state.newSectionTitle
        }),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
        .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error();
            }
            return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
        // you called these function now, instead after fetch
        // use () => 
        .then(() => this.getProjectSections(this.props.billProjId))
        .then(() => this.setState({ showSectionModal: false }))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem.  Thank you!